# Questions I asked on Super User are appearing on other websites

Tags: support, questions

I asked my [question on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/856786/mshta-exe-application-error-unable-to-install-windows-7-on-virtual-box) but when I search on Google I found some other website showing the same question by me or asked by some other user. These are on:

- `bighow.org/42237765-mshta_exe_Application_error___Unable_to_install_Windows_7_on_Virtual_box.html`
- `nerdanswer.com/answer.php?q=809415`
- `help.howproblemsolution.com/1081513/mshta-exe-application-error-unable-to-install-windows-7-on-virtual-box`

What is going on here?